# react-native shows unexpected Token while creating splashscreen

Tags: react-native

I am getting Unexpected Token in React Native, why trying to implement a simple splash screen.
My code looks somewhat like this

```
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createSwitchNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';
import SplashScreen from './components/Splashscreen';
import Login from './components/Login'

const HomeNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Splash: Splashscreen,
  Home: Login,
});

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Splash: 
    {
      screen: Splashscreen
    },
    Home: 
    {
      screen: Login
    },
    {
      initialRouteName:'Splash'
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

On line 23 / 34 thats where the error is. I am fairly new to this, what could I be getting wrong??

Line 23/24 has something like this

```
  21 |       screen: Login
  22 |     },
> 23 |     {
     |     ^
  24 |       initialRouteName:'Splash'
  25 |     }
  26 |   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your `navigationOptions` wrong, you are putting them in your `routeConfigs`. Move the `initialRouteName` out of the `routeConfigs` :

```
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Splash: 
    {
      screen: Splashscreen
    },
    Home: 
    {
      screen: Login
    }
  },
  {
     initialRouteName:'Splash'
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your routes separately, as your `createSwitchNavigator` will take two args.
your routes and navigation options.

Like: `createSwitchNavigator(<routes: arg1>, <navigationOptions:arg2>)`

```
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createSwitchNavigator
 } from 'react-navigation';
 import SplashScreen from './components/Splashscreen';
 import Login from './components/Login'

 const HomeNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Splash: Splashscreen,
  Home: Login,
 });   
 const RouteConfigs = {
  SplashScreen: {
  screen: Splashscreen
 },
 Home: {
  screen: Login
 }
};

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
 RouteConfigs,
 {
  initialRouteName: "SplashScreen"
 }
);
```